# Getting error INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Tags: android

I was trying to run the [Leaf Explorer](https://github.com/Shiv-Shambhu/Leaf-Explorer) and at the end while installing the app, I am getting this error.

> Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER:
> Scanning Failed.: Can't install because provider name
> org.monora.uprotocol.client.android.debug.fileprovider (in package
> com.leaf.explorer.pro.debug) is already used by
> com.genonbeta.TrebleShot.debug'

What can be the error here? I have tried many times and still the same error coming up? Please help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using app provider then change your authorities to dynamic

```
        **android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"**
```